# Is Event Calculus applied for program verification?

Tags: programming-languages, logic, software-verification

Recently I've read wiki page about [Robert Kowalski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Kowalski) (Prolog author) and stumbled upon interesting concept of [Event Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_calculus). The wiki article mentions only few applications of this logical language. I am wondering if any tools are using EC for program verification (similarly to Effect Systems).

**Is there any technology (language, library) applying Event Calculus for program verification?**